# Why is emitter voltage changing when input signal is applied in CE amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, class-a

When there is no input signal the emitter is at the bias quiescent voltage \$V_E\$.

I thought this would be the *average emitter voltage* even when the input signal is applied.(Because the input sinusoid *charges* the emitter bypass capacitor for 90 degrees, then *discharges* it by the *same amount* in the next 90 degrees)

However, when I simulate, the average emitter voltage is shifted to a new increased value as shown. Why is this happening?

(Top waveform is emitter voltage \$V_E\$, bottom waveform is input 10mV sine)
[image]

[image]

Comment: The time constant of your input DC-blocking circuit is ~0.5 s, but you only ran the simulation for 50 ms.

Comment: @ThePhoton ty but I also did a simulation for 5s. Average emitter voltage is still shifting. I posted the one with 50ms because the waveforms are easier to see.. I'm going to run the simulation for 5s again and update the results soon...

Comment: @ThePhoton you're correct! In 5s simulation, the average emitter voltage is slowly shifting down to the center with time. Thank you so much! But it is shifting down very very slowly. Doesn't look any close to 0.5s time constant :   https://prnt.sc/26w0ilt

Comment: Nvm, I decreased the capacitor values to 10u and now the emitter voltage is centered at the quiescent value XD You're awesome!! @ThePhoton